# How to model a chat application on Firebase Realtime Database?

Tags: database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

I am try to design a structure for chat application include private message and 
groups i by using real time firebase 
i don't know how to design the structure 
any help please
i am try to do something like this is that true
[image: structure for chat application]

```
Users
     |
     |_USER1
     |     |
     |     |__FRIENDS
     |     
     |_USER2
           |
           |__FRIENDS
```

Comment: Please list your concerns and tradeoffs you are considering

Answer (score 7):

You'll typically end up modeling the "chat rooms" in the database. So that each conversation (that users may see when they start the app), shows up as a separate node under some root list. You may want to separate the main metadata of each conversation from its actual messages and its participants.

So:

```
Chats
  chat1
    title: "...."
    lastUpdated: ...
  chat2
    title: "...."
    lastUpdated: ...
Messages
  chat1
    message1: { ... }
    message2: { ... }
  chat2
    message3: { ... }
    message3: { ... }
Participants
  chat1
    userid1: true
    userid2: true
  chat2
    userid1: true
    userid3: true
    userid4: true
    userid5: true
```

By using the same keys (`chat1`, `chat2`) for the nodes in each list, you can easily look up the data for a complete chat when needed. But by keeping them in separate top-level lists, you can better secure the app, and better control how much data is loaded.

Also see:

- [Best way to manage Chat channels in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33540479/best-way-to-manage-chat-channels-in-firebase)
- [What's a preferred way of creating a chatroom on Firebase/Swift for two matched users?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34033725/whats-a-preferred-way-of-creating-a-chatroom-on-firebase-swift-for-two-matched)
- [Allow users to send messages to multiple users simultaneously in a messaging app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51580191/allow-users-to-send-messages-to-multiple-users-simultaneously-in-a-messaging-app)