# Firebase data structure for one to one chat

Tags: firebase, data-structures, chat, nosql

I'm implementing one to one chat in firebase. I'm bit confuse with the data structure. There is best practice available for [firechat](https://firechat.firebaseapp.com/), but that's for group chat not for one to one chat.

I've design the following data structure, Can anyone suggests the better way or point correction.

```
chat-messages/
   <chat-id>
     <message-id>
        userId - The id of the user that sent the message.
        name - The name of the user that sent the message.
        message - The content of the message.
        timestamp - The time at which the message was sent.

chat-metadata/
   <chat-id>
        createdAt - The time at which the room was created.
        createdByUserId- The id of the user that created the room.
        id - The id of the room.

my-chats/
  <user-id>
     <other-user-id>
        chatId - The chat id

users/
  <user-id>
        id - The id of the user.
        name - The display name of the user.
```

In `my-chats` it will show the all of people user has done chatting. So for username1 and username2 there will be each entries for respective user like

```
my-chats
  username1
    username2
       chatId:-K6OqUkJRDpnOahGQ4rO
  username2
    username1
       chatId:-K6OqUkJRDpnOahGQ4rO
```

Comment: I'd model the room IDs after the user's in it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33540479/best-way-to-manage-chat-channels-in-firebase/33547123#33547123

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen but firebase supports length of ( 2 auth.uid + 'chat' ) ?

Comment: "A child node's key can be at most 768 bytes long" https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/understanding-data.html#section-limitations

Comment: So it'll be sufficient to hold two auth uid , right?