# Firebase Chat - Peer to Peer

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, chat

I am currently attempting to create a chat app, powered by Firebase. Ultimately, my goal is to allow users to message each other (pretty simple).
However, I am currently stuck on how to accomplish this.

Right now, I am able to create one huge, group chat, where users can post under different usernames. But, for ideal functionality, I would need users to be able to message each other directly, and not in one huge group chat.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: If your questions is "how can I model user-to-user chat rooms?", then see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33540479/best-way-to-manage-chat-channels-in-firebase/33547123#33547123

Answer (score 1):

If you go checkout JSQMessageViewController it is a pod that provides all the functionality of the messages app. They also have an example that is done by fireBase written in swift. That may be a great place to start and finish.

https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQMessagesViewController

Comment: Isn't that Group Chat only though?

Comment: even if it is just limit it to only two users in the chat and now its no longer group chat.

Comment: I use that library in my project and its great.

Comment: how to use this lib in swift 3 i need help in this @DanielLeonard

Comment: I would actually switch to MessageKit now it is the Swift version of this library. https://github.com/MessageKit/MessageKit