# Firebase Chat - Get messages just for 2 users

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2, nosql

I'm building a basic kind of whatsapp functionality for an app and I need to be able to query firebase for messages that match user1 and user2's IDs as noted below in receiver and sender.

I'm using Ionic 2 and I have both firebase and angularfire 2 libraries imported into the app already I am having a bit of trouble how I can pull all messages that contain both user1 and user2 but no other messages at all.

This is kind of what I am looking for but theres nothing in the docs that would support this kind of advanced query or possibly I have missed it. Thinking out loud its going to have to be some kind of correlated subquery or something like left joins on the same table (if it was mysql)

```
this.items2 = af.database.list('/messages', {
    query: {
      orderByChild_1: 'sender',
      equalTo: user1 || user2,
      and
      orderByChild_2: 'receiver',
      equalTo: user1 || user2,          
    }
  });
```

here is the database structure:

```
 messages:
    - Kc8da64IZjqv8PSsAGI
        message: "Hi How are you"
        receiver: "XRgPwmaPJWWIF8xLzvuQ28j5nKe2"
        sender: "ddL5H70N3hYW8n4WpDrhNfm32Fc2"

    - dkdwrehjdsfhaseuyr89
        message: "Im great and you ?"
        receiver: "ddL5H70N3hYW8n4WpDrhNfm32Fc2"
        sender: "XRgPwmaPJWWIF8xLzvuQ28j5nKe2"

    - i3uer8ufdisjhdsiflhlsdkhf
        message: "pretty good, where are you ?"
        receiver: "XRgPwmaPJWWIF8xLzvuQ28j5nKe2"
        sender: "ddL5H70N3hYW8n4WpDrhNfm32Fc2"

    - 23r9eyfdusikljnmsfjlskdjfklsjdfkl
        message: "Im in cuba"
        receiver: "XRgPwmaPJWWIF8xLzvuQ28j5nKe2"
        sender: "ddL5H70N3hYW8n4WpDrhNfm32Fc2"
```

Comment: Model chat rooms. Don't just keep one long list of messages between all users, but instead keep the messages between two (or any group of) users in a separate node from the others. That prevents the need for these complex (and expensive) queries. See my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33540479/best-way-to-manage-chat-channels-in-firebase, read [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/) and view [Firebase for SQL developers](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s).

Comment: That is very cool and solves some issues ive had in the back of my head whilst trying to figure out this other stuff.. thanks, btw I just read some other answers of your on this topic which are gonna help me out... dont suppose you have any other tricks that I could look at related to this

Comment: The three links I provided should give you a good basic understanding of NoSQL in general and Firebase specifically.

Comment: Sweet, been reading over them. very helpful. but when you want to list all the message threads pertaining to one user.. what would you recommend for that ? for instance I have a thread between 2 people with this id now: chat_XRgPwmaPJWWIF8xLzvuQ28j5nKe2_ddL5H70N3hYW8n4WpDrhNfm32Fc2 --- so how do I display all the messages that contain a given users id within that string ?

Comment: .. doesnt seem to cover that kind of scenario in the posts :)

Comment: Stop thinking of "I need to query this huge list of items to get these 3 things from it". Instead start modeling your data for the use-case. "I need to list the rooms that a user is in, so I should store the rooms/room ids for each user". `/userRooms/$uid: { room1: true, room2: true, room3: true }`

Comment: Sorry, I have still got an sql head - the only way I can see to do such a thing is to setup another collection/table that has each users ID and under that each string for the rooms like "chat_XRgPwmaPJWWIF8xLzvuQ28j5nKe2_ddL5H70N3hYW8n4WpDrhNfm32F‌​c2"  using the example you linked to for creating the "room" name I cant see any other way to do it other than this but i guess this is wrong because its very sql like ?

Comment: What you're describing is the same as the example I gave in my last comment, except that I simplified the room names there.

Comment: Cool.. I had already started to build it out that way :)