# How to structure Firestore database in chat app?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

The simplest way of storing chat messages is probably this:

```
message:
 -message1 {
   "user1"
   "user2"
   "message"
   "date"
  }
 -message2
 -message3
```

When the app grows in size (a lot of messages), and operations on database are done with `.whereEqualTo` are there any disadvantages of structuring chat app messages this way? Like with database iterating through all messages ?

Because if there are problems with this approach, i've seen for example this way of structuring database, that would segregate messages in different chat rooms

```
chats: {
    -chat1 {
      "lastMessage"
      "timestamp"
      "users": {user1, user2}
    }
    -chat2
    -chat3
  }

messages: {
 -chat1 {
  "message"
  "date"
 }
}
```

But in this example, adding new message would require user to make 2 write operations, one writing new message and one updating `chat` document with new `lastMessage` and `timestamp` client-side, or creating a cloud  function to update `chat` document with new values, when new message is added.

So, is the first option valid, or should I go with something like the second example?

Comment: If you are interested, you can also take a look at this [chat tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLn2n4GESV0Ak1HiH0tTPTJXsOEy-5v9qb). This is the [Firestore database schema](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u3KwKQddPoo&t=1s&list=PLn2n4GESV0Ak1HiH0tTPTJXsOEy-5v9qb&index=3).

Answer (score 45, accepted):

What you've offered as the first option is close to how you'd model this in a relation database in a `tblMessages`. Such a literal translation is seldom your best option in NoSQL databases, since they have very different trade-offs. For example, you've already noticed that you need to perform a query on two fields to get the messages between two users.

When modeling data on a NoSQL database, I usually recommend modeling in your database for what you see on your screen. So if your chat app has the concept of chat rooms (i.e. persistent chats between specific groups of people), I'd model those in your database too.

In Cloud Firestore that means that you'd have a top-level collection with a document for each chat room, and then a subcollection under each such document with the messages for that chat room:

```
ChatRooms (collection)
  ChatRoom1 (document)
    Messages (collection)
      Message1_1 (document)
      Message1_2 (document)
  ChatRoom2 (document)
    Messages (collection)
      Message2_1 (document)
      Message2_2 (document)
```

With this model you don't need to query to show the messages in a chat room, but can instead just load (all) the messages straight from the subcollection for that room. It also has the advantage that you partition the rooms, meaning that writes can scale much better.

I typically recommend modeling the [chat room document IDs after the participants](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33540479/best-way-to-manage-chat-channels-in-firebase) in the room, so that you can easily reconstruct the ID based on the participants. But there are more valid options for this.

Comment: So that's something like my second option, but combined to one collection, because if I wanted to add a listener to notify user of new message in any of those chatRooms i still need to keep something like `lastMessage` in `chatRoom` document, right?

Comment: I typically prefer to precalculate anything I can, so would definitely have a `lastUpdated` field in each room document.

Comment: You can find a similar use case in their official documentation.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model

Comment: My answer in the question I linked shows how to do create a list of chat rooms for each user.