# create private chat & group chat on different condition using firebase firestore in android

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, chat

I have to implement chat functionality in my existing app using firebase firestore but there are 2 cases:

1. **create private chat**- in this case i have the recyclerview that contain user list while i select particular user then start communication in current user & selected user.
2. **group chat**- in this case i have food item list & each food item has user list who send request to that food item now i want to allow current user to create group chat by adding those user who send request to that food item.

how to achieve those thing.

Comment: If you are using [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/), here you can find a tutorial on how to create a complete and functional [Firestore Chat App](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLn2n4GESV0Ak1HiH0tTPTJXsOEy-5v9qb).

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways on how to achieve the Chat application. It will depend on how you want or prefer to develop your database and application in general.

Considering that, I would recommend you take a look at the below articles, for more information and steps on how to achieve that.

These first 3 are more related to your private chat application part, that I think should help you.

- [[Make-A] Simple Chat Application using Cloud Firestore Part 1 – Introduction](https://imakeanapp.com/make-a-simple-chat-application-using-cloud-firestore-part-1-introduction/)
- [Firestore Megachat - Let's Build a Chat App](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LKAXg2drQJQ)
- [How to structure Firestore database in chat app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54008366/how-to-structure-firestore-database-in-chat-app)

This last one, I would recommend you take a look, as it provides more information regarding creating a Group Chat application with Firestore.

- [Group Chat with Firestore](https://fireship.io/lessons/build-group-chat-with-firestore/)

Let me know if the information helped you!