# set a real-time listener for collection with documents with two unique ids Firestore

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

I have this function which is called when page loads and displays the messages. I, however, need a real-time listener to display the messages posted to collection from the second user only. i.e when user2 sends a message and it is posted to collection and it is then updated on user1

```
function fetchMessages(){
    dbRef= db.collection("user").doc("eF1RFw3FVAO3LFJ8ORrf7oJPyR13").collection('messages').orderBy("dbTime", "asc");
    dbRef.get().then((snapshot) =>{
        snapshot.docs.forEach(doc =>{
            if(doc.data().id===1){
                renderUser1Messages(doc);
            }
            else{
                renderUser2Messages(doc);
            }

        });
    });
}
```

I was thinking of removing the whole function and making it all a snapshot listener. This works well when user2 sends a message, it is then displayed to user1 in realtime. However, now when user1 sends a message it is displayed twice. The listener am guessing fires and calls the function for user1 too with updated values from db.

```
    dbRef.onSnapshot(function(snapshot) {
    snapshot.docChanges().forEach(function(change) {
     if(change.type==="added" && (change.doc.data().id==="1")){
            renderUser1Messages(change.doc);
        } else
        if(change.type==="added" && (change.doc.data().id===2)){
            renderUser2Messages(change.doc);
        }
    }); 
});
```

How can I get around this behavior

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple types of changes that can happen in Firestore, and each is indicated by the value of [`change.type`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentChange#type):

1. A new document is added, which is indicated by a value of `added`. In this case you need to add the new document to your UI.
2. An existing document is removed, which is indicated by a value of `removed`. In this case you need to remove the existing UI elements for that document.
3. An existing document is changed, which is indicated by a value of `modified`. In this case you'll need to update the existing UI elements for that document.

Your code seems to only care about case 3, where a document is updated, but you're handling it as if a new document is added.

You'll need to instead find the existing UI element for the document, and update it. Alternative you can handle it by removing the existing UI element, and adding new UI elements for the document (so like case 2, followed by case 1).

---

A side-node on the way you query: if you have more than just document `1` and `2` in your database, your code will now download more documents than you need. I highly recommend in that case using two separate `onSnapshot` listeners, one on each of the documents you actually care about.