# How should I design a basic private chat structure?

Tags: nosql, google-cloud-firestore, chat

I am trying to create a basic chat app, only contains private messaging.

#### Background

I have two users, **user A** and **user B**.

```
users/A
- name: "John"
users/B
- name: "Mary"
```

When **user A** sends a message to **user B**, I create a conversation between those two. In this case conversation id would be A_B. [Read more here.](https://medium.com/@ngengesenior/database-structure-of-one-to-one-chat-app-with-firebase-93f813184dfe)

```
user-conversations/A/B # A for user A, B for user B
 - conversationId: A_B
user-conversations/B/A # B for user B, A for user A
 - conversationId: A_B
```

And I have user-conversations collections. I've created this structure because when **user A** opens the app, I want to show his conversations with **user B** name and image. With this structure, I just need to have an userId, then I can retrieve his/her conversations with other user's informations.

And of course I have conversations collection which includes messages.

```
conversations/A_B/messages # A_B is conversationId between user A and user B
 - text: "hey"
 - sender: "A"
```

## Question

So, how can I improve my database structure, specifically user-conversations collection. Because, when someone wants to read or write to conversations/A_B, I want be sure that user is allowed to write and I could achieve that only if I have conversationId associated with user's.

Comment: Here you can find a tutorial on how to create a complete and functional [Firestore one to one Chat App](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLn2n4GESV0Ak1HiH0tTPTJXsOEy-5v9qb).

Comment: Thank you, I've already watched your tutorial but honestly I couldn't understand your structure. I think it's too complicated for my app.

Comment: That's the simples structure for a one to one chat app.

Comment: Your approach sounds fine to me. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33540479/best-way-to-manage-chat-channels-in-firebase, which also indicates that it's normal to need a lookup list for the chat rooms of each user.