# How to connect two users in firebase?

Tags: android, database, firebase, authentication

I want to create a chat app and I want to create rooms inside.

The rooms should be created to chat with other users on the app.

---

I want to know how to connect two users

where when someone creates a room to chat with you you should see the room too in your account and

start chatting together.

Comment: Go through (this)[https://www-scaledrone-com.cdn.ampproject.org/v/s/www.scaledrone.com/blog/android-chat-tutorial/amp/?amp_js_v=a2&amp_gsa=1&usqp=mq331AQCKAE%3D#aoh=15723772018001&referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com&amp_tf=From%20%251%24s&ampshare=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.scaledrone.com%2Fblog%2Fandroid-chat-tutorial%2F] tutorial

Comment: Or [this](https://www-pubnub-com.cdn.ampproject.org/v/s/www.pubnub.com/blog/android-getting-started/amp/?amp_js_v=a2&amp_gsa=1&usqp=mq331AQCKAE%3D#aoh=15723772018001&referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com&amp_tf=From%20%251%24s&ampshare=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.pubnub.com%2Fblog%2Fandroid-getting-started%2F)

Comment: Or this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33540479/best-way-to-manage-chat-channels-in-firebase :)