# valueEventListener onDataChanged returns previous value after updating children

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i'm working on an App that updates the value of some data(`FirebaseDatabse`) once an activity is created i.e opening the chat screen updates the database values of `isSeen` to `true`, but `ref.child("path").addValueEventListener` `onDataChange` returns the previous values of data before it was updated... **it doesn't return the updated values**

Default values:  [image]

Updating:

```
private fun seenMsg(userID: String){

    seenListener = myRef.child("Chats").addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener{
        override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {}
        override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {

            for (sp in p0.children){

                val chat = sp.getValue(Chat::class.java)!!

                Log.d("TAG", "    MessageActivity VALUE : $chat    ") // isSeen = false

                if (chat.receiver.equals(firebaseUser!!.uid) && chat.sender.equals(userID)){

                    val cMap = HashMap<String, Any>()
                    cMap["isSeen"] = true
                    sp.ref.updateChildren(cMap)

                    Log.d("TAG", "   MessageActivity AFTER UPDATING : $chat    ") // isSeen still false here
                }
            }
        }
    })
}
```

updated value:  [image]

retrieving data:

```
private fun retrieveMsg(senderID: String, receiverID: String?, imageUrl: String) {

    ref.child("Chats").addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener{
        override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {}
        override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
            chatList.clear()

            for (sp in p0.children){
                val chat = sp.getValue(Chat::class.java)!!

                Log.d("TAG", "    MessageActivity Retrieve : $chat    ")

                if ((chat.receiver).equals(senderID) && chat.sender.equals(receiverID)
                    || chat.receiver.equals(receiverID) && chat.sender.equals(senderID)){

                    chatList.add(chat)
                }

                chatsAdapter = ChatsAdapter(this@MessageChatActivity, chatList, imageUrl)
                recyclerView.adapter = chatsAdapter
            }
        }
    })

}
```

**Logcat:**

```
2020-06-08 22:57:25.965 20668-20668/com.x.chatapp D/TAG:     MessageActivity Retrieve : Chat(sender=ftTTpG0IJ8OKMFBMDaZ7fws28g02, message=1, receiver=R4scdWQFLzVLp8StLGzSqDJ6mBr2, url=, isSeen=false, messsageID=-M9Kigi8g92_yy9EWK9I)    
2020-06-08 22:57:25.966 20668-20668/com.x.chatapp D/TAG:     MessageActivity Retrieve : Chat(sender=ftTTpG0IJ8OKMFBMDaZ7fws28g02, message=2, receiver=R4scdWQFLzVLp8StLGzSqDJ6mBr2, url=, isSeen=false, messsageID=-M9Kigi8g92_yy9EWK9I)
```

> `isSeen` is still false even when true in database

Comment: Not related to the problem, but I **highly** recommend modeling your data a bit less like a SQL table. I'd instead model chat rooms as separate nodes, as shown here: chat https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33540479/best-way-to-manage-chat-channels-in-firebase

Comment: Are you sure the `sp.ref.updateChildren(cMap)` is actually written to the database? For example, when you check the same nodes in the Firebase console, are they updated?

Comment: Chats are modeled well separately, I uploaded pictures showing the updated value from the databese...

Comment: Hmm... I'm not sure why the listener wouldn't pick that value up. Did you call `retrieveMsg` before or after `seenMsg`? It shouldn't make a difference, but I'm not sure what could be causing this.

Comment: If you consider at some point in time to try using [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/), here you can find a tutorial on how to create a complete and functional [Firestore Chat App using Kotlin](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLn2n4GESV0Ak1HiH0tTPTJXsOEy-5v9qb).

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that, i had to delete the `google-json` file and download a new one, then  **clean project**.