# How to create a unique ID from 2 different UIDs in Firebase?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to develop a chat app and wanted to know what if there's any way to generate a unique ID between 2 different users.

Comment: Some like this you mean? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33540479/best-way-to-manage-chat-channels-in-firebase