# Query stored values that contain specific string

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a small realtime firebase database that's set up like this:

```
database
-messages
--XXXXXXXXXXXX
---id : "XXX-XXX"
---content : "Hello world!"
```

It's a very simple message system, the id field is basically a combination of users id from my mysql database. I'm trying to return all messages that match one of the ids, either sender or receiver. But I can't do it, seems like firebase only support exacts querys. Could you give me some guidanse?
Here's the code I'm working with

```
firebase.database().ref("messages").orderByChild("id").equalTo(userId).on("value", function(snapshot)
```

I'm looking for something like ".contains(userId)"

Answer (score 0):

Firebase supports exact matches (with `equalTo`) and so-called prefix queries where the value **starts with** a certain value (by combining `startAt` and `endAt`). It does not support querying for values that **end** with a certain value.

I recommend keeping a mapping from each user IDs to their `messages` nodes, somewhere separately in their database.

So say that you have:

```
messages: {
  "XXXXXXXXXXXX": {
    id : "YYY-ZZZ",
    content : "Hello world!"
  }
}
```

You also have the following mappings:

```
userMessages: {
  "YYY": {
    "XXXXXXXXXXXX": true
  },
  "ZZZ": {
    "XXXXXXXXXXXX": true
  }
}
```

Now with this information you can look up the messages for each user based on their ID.

For more on the modeling of this type of data, I recommend:

- [Best way to manage Chat channels in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33540479/best-way-to-manage-chat-channels-in-firebase)
- [Many to Many relationship in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41527058/many-to-many-relationship-in-firebase)
- this artcle on [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/)

Comment: Thank you, I'm taking a look, it's quite complex, it seems plain javascript doesn't support mapping also?

Comment: Hey @Logista Did you get anywhere with this?

Comment: Nope, sorry. I gave up, firebase is more trouble than it's worth, I moved to server sent events may be slower but it behaves like I want it to