# How user OR AND Operators in Where clause firestore flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

In Chatting Application I am using StreamBuilder and in stream I am using it. Where layout show sender and reciever messages.

```
.where
  '(RecieverId == $RecieverId && SenderId == ${_auth.currentUser!.uid}) || (RecieverId == ${_auth.currentUser!.uid} && SenderId == $RecieverId)'
  )
```

Comment: In Chatting Application I am using StreamBuilder and in stream I am using it. Where layout show sender and reciever messages

Answer (score 0):

This type of condition is not possible in Firestore without modifying your data structure. My common approach is to have a field `participants` where you concatenate the UIDs of the two users in lexicographical order. With that field you could then query it with:

```
.where("participants", "==", "uidOfMuhammad_uidOfPuf")
```

The ordering of the UIDs is key here, as it removes the distinction between sender and receiver (so you'll still need your `RecieverId` and `SenderId`). For more on this model, also have a look at [Best way to manage Chat channels in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33540479/best-way-to-manage-chat-channels-in-firebase).