# Flutter: How to implement random chat rooms with firebase?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am currently trying to develop a random chat application which matches users randomly and allows them to chat and then add each other as friends (if they enjoyed the chat) in order to continue the chat.

So now I need to solve three problems:

1. match users randomly

My idea would be to implement a method which randomly picks two user ids from my users collection. But I do not know how to implement this in code - Can anybody help here?

2. craete a chat room to store the messages

This is the most difficult part. Currently my idea is to create a collection called "chats" and add a document which is named "$uid of user 1 & $uid of user2" where I save the messages. But I do not know how that would look in code and whether this actually solves the problem.

3. create a friend list

My idea is to create a list inside each user document and save the user ids of all friends. How could that be implemented in code? And is there a better solution to that?

Comment: For #2, the approach sounds good, and you can find a code sample here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33540479/best-way-to-manage-chat-channels-in-firebase. If you're having trouble implementing that in Flutter, open a new question with a [minimal repro](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of where you got stuck.

Answer (score 0):

> For  craete a chat room to store the messages Here is solution

First of all check Chat Room Is exist or not With these code

```
 static Future isChatRoomExist(String id1, String id2) async {
var room1 = await chatRoom.doc("$id1-$id2").get();
var room2 = await chatRoom.doc("$id2-$id1").get();

bool isExist = false;
String currectRoomId = "";
if (room1.exists) {
  currectRoomId = "$id1-$id2";
  isExist = true;
}
if (room2.exists) {
  currectRoomId = "$id2-$id1";
  isExist = true;
}
return {"isExist": isExist, "chatRoomId": currectRoomId};
```

}