# Firebase Realtime Database Rules Permission Denied

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I have an app where I am using a custom authentication method. First, on the user login into the app, I generate the JWT Token on the server and send it back to the app.

```
function generateJWT($con,$userID,$cretedTime) {
    $secret_Key  = "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\HCPW\nAtY9K1/19yScEhdmhw8Ozek=\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n";
    $date   = time();
    //$expire_at     = $date->modify('+3 minutes')->getTimestamp(); // Add 60 seconds
    $domainName = "firebase-adminsdk-XXXXXXXX.iam.gserviceaccount.com";

    $request_data = [
    'iss'  => $domainName, 
    'sub' => $domainName,
    'aud' => "https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/google.identity.identitytoolkit.v1.IdentityToolkit",
    'iat'  => $date,         // Issued at: time when the token was generated
                              // Issuer
    //'exp' => $date+(60*60),  // Maximum expiration time six month in seconds //15778476 
    'uid' => $userID,                     // User name
    'created' => $cretedTime,                     // User name
    ];
     $newToken = JWT::encode($request_data,$secret_Key,'RS256');        
     return $newToken; 
    
}
```

Then In the app send on receiving this token I am start the login process.my app using custom firebase auth

```
firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
firebaseAuth.signInWithCustomToken(Session.getJWT())
        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if (task.isComplete()){
                    if(getActivity()!=null){
                     //User Logged In Successfully 
                    }else{
                        // Failed
                    }

                }
            }
        });
```

So after days of googling, I got the Firebase rules for the structure of my database to look like this

```
{
  "Chat": {
    "206-4": "",
    "311-158": "",
    "215-112": "",
    "734-115": "",
    "734-55": "",
    "734-468": "",
    "34-32": "",
    "534-179": "",
    "734-345": {
      "-NI7hqW3YTFKpnSZU422": {
        "Message": "Test",
        "Message_From": "Support ",
        "Message_From_ID": "4",   
        "Message_To": "Demo",
        
      },
      "-NMVOwlAqmyIA52QU9F-": {
        "Message": "Hi",
        "Message_From": "Support ",
        "Message_From_ID": "4",
        "Message_To": "Demo",
        
      }
    },    
    "347-234": {
      "-NI7hXybU02Mg6vYqdKp": {
        "Message": "Ohio",
        "Message_From": "Elaxer  Support ",
        "Message_From_ID": "4",
        "Message_To": "Demo 2",
        
      }
    },
    "281-69": "",
    "317-34": ""
  },
  "Users": {
    "4": {
      "Online": false,
      "lastSeen": "1675785660782"
    },    
    "284": {
      "Online": false,
      "lastSeen": "1673611185873"
    }
  },
  "UsersLocations": {
    "4-210": {
      "-1": {
        "Latitude": "22.605",
        "Longitude": "88.375"
      }
    },
    "25-21": {
      "-1": {
        "Latitude": "22.605",
        "Longitude": "88.375"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Firebase Rules

```
{
  "rules": {
    "Chat": {
      "$room_id": {
        ".read": "auth.uid === $room_id && $room_id.beginsWith(auth.uid + '-') || auth.uid === $room_id && $room_id.endsWith('-' + auth.uid)",
        ".write": "auth.uid === $room_id && $room_id.beginsWith(auth.uid + '-') || auth.uid === $room_id && $room_id.endsWith('-' + auth.uid)"
      }
    },
    "Users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
    },
    "UsersLocations": {
      "$user_location_id": {
        ".read": "auth.uid === $user_location_id && $user_location_id.endsWith('-location')",
        ".write": "auth.uid === $user_location_id && $user_location_id.endsWith('-location')"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So when ever i tried to create or get the Chat node (Chatroom).

```
DatabaseReference db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Chat");
db.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {           
    }
});
```

It gives me error

> Listen at /Chat failed: DatabaseError: Permission denied

I am not able to understand why i am getting this error when i am only checking the user id exist in room name and my jwt token on generation time having user id of one user. Please help me out, what's wrong i am doing with my rules

Answer (score 1):

As Alex also answered: you're not granting anyone read access to `/Chat`, so any code trying to read from there will be rejected. I would not recommend his answer though, as the rule on `/Chat` makes the more strict rules on `/Chat/$room_id` meaningless.

I recommend reading the documentation on [rules don't filter data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#rules_are_not_filters) (which explains why your current code don't work and on the fact that [permissions cascade](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/core-syntax#read_and_write_rules_cascade) (which explains why the rules in Alex' answer make the ones you already have meaningless).

The data structure you have look like what I described in my answer to: [Best way to manage Chat channels in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33540479/best-way-to-manage-chat-channels-in-firebase). In my answer there I also showed how to model security rules to allow read access and how to get a list of the chat room for the user, so I recommend checking that out.

---

As I tried explaining in the comments, the way you handle the sign-in result is wrong:

```
// ❌ THIS IS WRONG ❌ 
firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
firebaseAuth.signInWithCustomToken(Session.getJWT())
    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            if (task.isComplete()){
                if(getActivity()!=null){
                 //User Logged In Successfully 
                }else{
                    // Failed
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Instead, when a `Task` completes you should check whether it succeeded or failed, as shown in the documentation on [handling tas results](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/tasks#handling_task_results). In your case that'd be:

```
// ✅ Handling success and failure correctly 
firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
firebaseAuth.signInWithCustomToken(Session.getJWT())
    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()!=null) {
                // User signed in
                // TODO: access database
            } else {
                // Sign in failed
                throw task.getException();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Even the basic `{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth.uid != null",
    ".write": "auth.uid != null"
  }
}
` get permission denied message. Why? and how can i debug the auth.uid value

Comment: That sounds like no user is signed in. Run `Log.i("Firebase", FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser());` right before you try to access the database.

Comment: Is my custom token with JWT sign up with firebaseAuth is correct?

Comment: You can test that yourself by checking what result you get in the `onComplete` of your `signInWithCustomToken`. If the sign in completes successfully your JWT is correct. If the sign in fails, there's an error message in `task.getException()` that tells you what went wrong.

Comment: Yes if you notice the `firebaseAuth.signInWithCustomToken` i only letting user to proceed (login) if the method calls `onComplete`

Comment: A **completed** task can still have **failed** or **succeeded**. https://developers.google.com/android/guides/tasks

Comment: I checked the link and I'm using `onComplete` and then again i check `if(task.isComplete())` . So by this code i guess it's getting success in signing. But if you can shed some light on my logic that would be really helpful for me.

Comment: Guessing it not going to help here. As said: a **completed** task can still have **failed** or **succeeded**. The link I gave has examples for explicit `addOnSuccessListener` and `addOnFailureListener` listener calls, but also for the `addOnCompleteListener` that you use and how to check `isSuccessful` in there.

Comment: I added an example of this to my answer.

Comment: You are right and i think i need to ask separate question for help in generating token. I think i have found the root cause After using your code: `com.google.android.gms.tasks.RuntimeExecutionException: com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException: The custom token format is incorrect. Please check the documentation.`