# I want to Firebase Realtime Database rules include auth.uid

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

This is my DB:

[image: db]

Each key was created by combining the user name.
I want to make sure that only the members within each piece of data are accessible.

```json
{
  "rules": {
    "chatroom": {
      ".write": "auth != null",
      "$room_id": {
        ".read": "$room_id.contains(auth.uid)"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Since each key was created by combining the user name,

I thought I could use this `.contains` function to limit who can access it.
In Flutter,

```
lastQuery = db.ref('chatroom').orderByChild('date');

data = await lastQuery.limitToLast(10).once();
```

But occurred Error:

> [firebase_database/permission-denied] Client doesn't have permission to access the desired data.

With all allowed rules, this code works fine.
For example,

```json
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "true",
    ".write": "true"
  }
}
```

```json
{
  "rules": {
    "chatroom": {
      ".write": "auth != null",
      "$room_id": {
        ".read": "data.child('member').child(auth.uid).val() == true",
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Try this rules, Because key, value in member, it is made of UID : Bool.

This also causes an error.

What should I do?

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097)

Comment: Debug questions require a [mre]. [ask] [Help]

Comment: Because code worked fine with the allowed rules, I didn't know it was a problem. I'm sorry.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. Please use enough words & phrases & references to things & to parts of things to be clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase's [security rules don't filter data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/core-syntax#rules-not-filters). Rather they merely ensure that the code is only trying to read data that it is allowed to access.

That's why the code and rules always go hand-in-hand: the code must request exactly the nodes that you want it to be able to read, and then the rules must ensure that only those requests are allowed.

---

So when you do this in your code:

```
lastQuery = db.ref('chatroom').orderByChild('date');

data = await lastQuery.limitToLast(10).once();
```

The rules engine checks if the user has read permission on the `chatroom` node. And since there's no `.read` clause on that node or above it, the operation gets rejected.

---

While you *can* [define a condition for a query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/rules-conditions#query-based_rules) in your rules, those won't work here - as you can't mimic the `contains` operation from the rules in your actual code.

The idiomatic approach is to create an *additional* top-level node where you track the chatroom IDs that each user has access to. So something like:

```
userChatrooms: {
  "$uid1": {
    "$chatroomId1": true,
    "$chatroomId2": true
  },
  "$uid2": {
    "$chatroomId1": true,
    "$chatroomId3": true
  },
  "$uid3" {
    "$chatroomId2": true,
    "$chatroomId3": true
  }

}
```

With such a structure in place, you can:

1. First read the chatroom IDs that the user has access to, based on their UID, from `/userChatrooms/$uid`. It's also easy to secure this structure with [owner-only access](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/basics#content-owner_only_access).
2. Then read each chat room's contents in turn from `/chatroom/$chatroomID`. Now your current rules work, since you no longer need to read the while root `chatroom` node, and you've already sufficiently secured access to the individual rooms with your current rules.

Also see: [Best way to manage Chat channels in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33540479/best-way-to-manage-chat-channels-in-firebase)

Comment: Thank you, I think I was inexperienced in using queries. I realized that the rules meant no filtering of data and only permissions to access the endpoint.